# Cкрытая страница php

Tags: php, mysql

Без вас не справиться, слишком глупый )
Облазил кучу форумов, и статей, ничего не работает.
Вообщем суть такова, есть страничка авторизации, судя по 
if ($data['user_role'] == '1'){
    header("Location: admin.php"); exit(); 
    Насколько мне подсказали, если взять с бд юзера у которого будет роль "1", то он перенаправляется на страницу админа, все работает (хоть и структура откровенно плохая), так вот, как теперь на странице admin.php проверить, залогинился ли именно персонаж с ролью "1", а не кто угодно смог зайти на нее просто введя в строку /admin.php Читал про сессии, но таковых в моем коде как я понял нету, плюсом ко всему, нужно добавить кнопку "разлогиниться" на той же страничке.
Заранее благодарен.

```html
<?php
// Страница авторизации

// Функция для генерации случайной строки
function generateCode($length=6) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHI JKLMNOPRQSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $code = "";
    $clen = strlen($chars) - 1;
    while (strlen($code) < $length) {
            $code .= $chars[mt_rand(0,$clen)];
    }
    return $code;
}

// конекшн
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "usersdb");

$message;

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // login = bd
    $query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT user_id, user_password, user_role FROM users WHERE user_login='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['login'])."' LIMIT 1");
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
    
    // pass=bd
    if($data['user_password'] === md5(md5($_POST['password'])))
    {
        //ген код
        $hash = md5(generateCode(10));

        // Записываем в БД новый хеш авторизации и IP
        mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE users SET user_hash='".$hash."' ".$insip." WHERE user_id='".$data['user_id']."'");

        // Ставим куки
        setcookie("id", $data['user_id'], time()+60*60*24*30,"/");
        setcookie("hash", $hash, time()+60*60*24*30,"/"); // httponly !!!
        setcookie("role", $data['user_role']);
        // редирект
    if ($data['user_role'] == '1'){
    header("Location: admin.php"); exit();
    }
    else{
    header("Location: algoritm.php"); exit();
    }
    header("Location: algoritm.php"); exit();
    }
    else
    {
        print "Вы ввели неправильный логин/пароль";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В самом начале `admin.php`:

```
if(empty($_COOKIE['role'] || $_COOKIE['role'] != 1)) exit('No rights');
```

Разлогиниться, пример `logout.php`:

```
//first example
foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value){
    $_COOKIE[$key] = '';
}
//second example
foreach($_COOKIE as $key => $value){
        setcookie($key, '', time()-3600);
}
```

Рекомендую к прочтению [cookie](https://metanit.com/web/php/4.2.php), [session](http://www.softtime.ru/bookphp/gl8_1.php). Внятно и просто написано для новичков, только в статьях php 4 (хотя принципы работы не изменились).

Comment: Не нужно делать за лентяев их работу. :)) А то так и будут приходить на stack за "готовым решением".

Answer (score 0):

Перед авторизацией проверяйте куку. Если она у юзера есть, забирайте данные из них, делайте запрос в БД. Если запись с данными из куки есть, значит "сессию" можно считать активной, и сразу перенаправляйте юзера на страницу админки. Если нет, тогда авторизовывайте и устанавливайте куку.

Функция "разлогиниться" ещё проще. Берёте данные из кук ищите в базе, удаляете запись. Удаляете куку. Перенаправляете юзера на index.php

Comment: Мысль понял,а вот в кодинге я плох.
Поэтому и обратился за готовым решением...

Comment: @SamuraiSidzygohara А, вон как. Ну тогда вам не на stack, а на фриланс! :) Я думаю за относительно небольшие деньги вашу проблему решат за часик-другой.